# Why I get redirected too many times only in nested subdirectory?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

I am trying to run wordpress in a subdirectory `blog` in my rails app, I used this nginx config as:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  root /var/www/mydomain/current/public;



location /blog {
  root /var/www/example/current;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}

}
```

if I visit my rails app, at `https://example.com` it loads fine
if I visit wordpress frontend at `https://example.com/blog` it loads fine
if I visit wordpress admin at `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin` I get this result:

```
mydomain.com redirected you too many times.
```

My folders looks like this:

```
/rails_app/
/rails_app/blog/
/rails_app/blog/wp-admin/
```

where `blog` directory has wordpress files

Any idea?

**edit**

I have previous attempt before using nginx to use wordpress into rails subdirectory, here is part of my `config/routes.rb`

```
match '/blog', :controller=>'wordpress', :via => [:get], :action=>'fetch'
match '/blog/:slug', :controller=>'wordpress', :via => [:get], :action=>'fetch'
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file and the relevant controller that this route is hitting please

Comment: kindly see edit above

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the multiple redirects are coming from your `app/controllers/wordpress_controller.rb` file - could you post the contents of that too please :)

Comment: I have removed the all the routes starting with `match '/blog/` I still have the issue

Comment: That is because that route directs you to the wordpress controller, and that is where you are redirecting multiple times. Without seeing your wordpress controller I can't help you - it's localted at `app/controllers/wordpress_controller.rb`.

Comment: I don't think so, as I have deleted all routes pointing to `wordpress_controller.rb` and I even deleted the controller it self..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem, and by adding the following code in wp-config.php problem was resolved.

```
if ( 'https' === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
              $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
              $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '443';
}
```